# Click function with window height variable on load and resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, resize

I have a simple click function that scrolls the page to a certain point. That point needs to be 1/2 the height plus 650px. My code below works perfectly on load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var scroll = $(window).innerHeight()*.5+650;
    $('a#start').click(function () {
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: scroll }, 1500, "easeOutCirc");
      return false;
  });

});
```

The problem is that it does not recalculate the height on window resize. I tried the following to no avail:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

  var scroll = $(window).innerHeight()*.5+650;
  $('a#start').click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: scroll }, 1500, "easeOutCirc");
    return false;
  });

});
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried to use `document` instead of `window` for you resize function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you declaring a click event inside the resize handler?

Just do the height calculation inside the click function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a#start').click(function () {

      var wh=$(window).innerHeight(), scroll = wh*.5+650;

      $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop: scroll }, 1500, "easeOutCirc");
      return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: Well, honestly, this was just the closest I could get in terms of a solution. I'm just trying to illustrate essentially what I'm trying to do. Your solution got me closer but has two issues. 1) it first scrolls the page to the original height calculation and then adjusts to the proper height and 2) once this is complete, the page is locked up and I am unable to scroll.

Comment: They are listed in my response. I tried to create a line break (by hitting 'return' and it submitted before I finished so I had to edit my response. Thanks.

Comment: I modified my answer slightly, but I'm not sure if it solves the issues.

Comment: OK, we're definitely closer. The issue now is that the calculation is off. It is scrolling to a point consistently and it works exactly the same on load and resize, but it's not scrolling to the desired point. Also, the amount that it is off is relative to the window height, so it's not like I can just adjust the 650 number. I'm not sure where the discrepancy is...

Comment: I just did a little test and it appears that the code you provided assumes the window is always 1300. It's using 650 as the wh*.5 value. Always, regardless of the actual window height. Does this help?

Comment: One more thing. Not sure if my comment makes sense. If I set my window height to exactly 1300px, it works perfectly. If I reduce my window height I end up short and if I increase my window height above 1300 it works perfectly still. So, your code works if my window is 1300px in height or above..

Comment: Alright, it looks like we have a winner. I took out your conditional statement and it works! I'm not 100% sure why this works and your first suggestion didn't (they seem very similar), but it works. Thanks so much! (I'll update your code with the final version.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).resize and not $(window).resize
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no change. Same result. Thanks!